# Is it possible setup headers in AWS Athena CSV files?

Tags: csv, header, amazon-athena, presto

I have an AWS Athena service in place.
After the query Athena generates an CSV file.
Let's say I want to see the follow result (with headers) when I open that CSV in the excel or google sheet. 
[image]

For the line 7 to 13 it is ok. It is actual result from Athena.
I want to add a header (like in the picture).

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Presto supports `skip.header.line.count` table property since 0.199 (Athena is essentially Presto 0.172), but I am not sure whether it applies to CSV files. Did you try Presto directly (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07DKV5659) or Presto on EMR?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, because Athena doesn't support that and also it isn't compatible with CSV format. If you want to add "headers" you can use a workaround by using "union all", but it will not give you the result as you expect.

About CSV format:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 0):

Even when it is something dirty, I have seen it the use of those headers for avoiding values repetition. I will use my own sample file here and you can adapt it later:

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer | John Smith | -- | -- | -- |
| order_id | ORD_212345 | -- | -- | -- |
| date | 10/5/2012 | -- | -- | -- |
| currency | EUR | -- | -- | -- |
| product_id | product_name | price | unit | amount |
| PID_1234 | Sugar | 1.20 | Kg | 12.00 |
| PID_2345 | Farina | 2.10 | Kg | 20.00 |
| PID_3455 | Egg | 1.05 | Unit | 200.00 |
| PID_3555 | Honey | 3.85 | Liter | 3.00 |

the first four rows are the *dirty* header, they are supposed to represent data repeated for all the rest of the rows. The result would be like this:

| customer | order_id | date | currency | product_id | product_name | price | unit | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | ORD_212345 | 10/5/2012 | EUR | PID_1234 | Sugar | 1.20 | Kg | 12.00 |
| John Smith | ORD_212345 | 10/5/2012 | EUR | PID_2345 | Farina | 2.10 | Kg | 20.00 |
| John Smith | ORD_212345 | 10/5/2012 | EUR | PID_3455 | Egg | 1.05 | Unit | 200.00 |
| John Smith | ORD_212345 | 10/5/2012 | EUR | PID_3555 | Honey | 3.85 | Liter | 3.00 |

One possible query would be:

```
WITH
  RAW_DATA AS (
   SELECT
     col0, col1, col2, col3, col4,
     , "$path" file
     , row_number() over () as row_num
   FROM
     "database"."orders"
),
HEADER_ROWS AS (
   SELECT
     col0 key
   , col1 value
   , file
   FROM
     "database"."orders"
   WHERE row_num between 1 and 4
) 
, DATA_ROWS AS (
   SELECT
     col0 product_id
   , col1 product_name
   , col2 price
   , col3 unit
   , col4 amount
   , file
   FROM
     "database"."orders"
   WHERE (NOT (row_num between 1 and 5))
) 
, HEADER AS (
   SELECT
     file
   , "map_agg"(key, value) header
   FROM
     HEADER_ROWS
   GROUP BY file
) 
, ALL_DATA AS (
   SELECT
   , header['customer'] customer
   , header['order_id'] order_id
   , header['date'] date
   , header['currency'] currency
   , data_row.product_id
   , data_row.product_name
   , data_row.price
   , data_row.unit
   , data_row.amount
   FROM
     (HEADER
   INNER JOIN DATA_ROWS data_row ON (HEADER.file = data_row.FILE))
)
SELECT * FROM ALL_DATA
```

If you just want to skip the header files:

```
   SELECT
     *, row_number() over () as row_num
   FROM
     "mytable"
   WHERE NOT (row_num between 1 and 7)
```